# How to update only few columns of an Entity by a form

Tags: php, html, symfony

I have a `User` Entity and I collect all the data in a form called `Register`. But once after registering, I want to edit some of the fields of a user by a form. But some fields are avoided being updated (email) and Password field is optional. I tried rendering the same register form but `$form->handleRequest($request)` throws an error saying:

> Expected argument of type "string", "NULL" given at property path
>   "password".

I want to know if there is a way to do this?

I tried `$form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()),false);`
instead of `$form->handleRequest($request);` but it didn't work.

// This is my controller.

```
/**
 * @Route("/update/{id}", name="update")
 * @param $id
 * @param Request $request
 * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
 * @param UserRepository $userRepository
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|Response
 */

public function updateUser($id,Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder, UserRepository $userRepository){
    $user = $userRepository->find($id);

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
        ->add('email',EmailType::class,[
            'label'=>'Email',
            'required' => false,
            'attr'=>['placeholder'=>"Email"]
        ])
        ->add('password',RepeatedType::class,[
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
            'required' => false,
            'options' => ['attr' => ['class' => 'password-field']],
            'first_options'  => ['label' => 'Password','attr'=>['placeholder'=>"Password"]],
            'second_options' => ['label' => 'Confirm Password','attr'=>['placeholder'=>"Confirm Password"]],
        ])
        ->add('firstName',TextType::class,['label'=>'First Name',  'attr'=>['placeholder'=>"First Name"]])
        ->add('lastName',TextType::class,['label'=>'Last Name','attr'=>['placeholder'=>"Last Name"]])
        ->add('address',TextareaType::class,['required' => false,'label'=>'Address','attr'=>['placeholder'=>"Address"]])
        ->add('idNumber',TextType::class,['label'=>'NIC Number','attr'=>['placeholder'=>"NIC Number"]])
        ->add('phoneNumber',TelType::class,['label'=>'Phone Number','attr'=>['placeholder'=>"Phone Number"]])
        ->add('image',FileType::class,['label'=>'Photo','required'=>false,'attr'=>['hidden'=>"hidden", 'accept'=>"image/jpeg, image/png"]])
        ->add('save',SubmitType::class,[
            'label'=>'Register',
            'attr' => [
                'class'=>"btn btn-outline-success float-right"
            ]
        ])
        ->getForm();


    $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){

            if($user->getPassword() !=""){
                $user->setPassword($passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user,$user->getPassword()));
            }

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
        }


    return $this->render('register/update.html.twig', [
        'form'=>$form->createView(),
    ]);

}
```

// And this is my TWIG file.

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Edit Info{% endblock %}
{% block refHome %}{{ path('main') }}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    <div class="container" style=" margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;margin-top: 1cm;" >
        <div class="row">
            {#            <div class="col-lg-2"></div>#}
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <div class="card" style="width: 50rem;text-align: center;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h3 class="card-title float-left">Edit Info</h3>
                        <div style="margin-top: 2cm;">
                            <p class="card-text">

                            <form name="register" id="register_form"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <div id="register">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                                {{ form_errors(form.firstName) }}
                                                {{ form_widget(form.firstName) }}
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                                {{ form_errors(form.lastName) }}
                                                {{ form_widget(form.lastName) }}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div style="margin-top: 0.5cm;"></div>

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
                                                {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-5">

                                                {{ form_errors(form.idNumber) }}
                                                <input type="text"  id="register_idNumber" placeholder="NIC Number" onkeypress="isInputNumber(event)" pattern="^[0-9]{9}[a-zA-Z]$" value="{{ form.idNumber.vars.value }}" name="register[idNumber]" required="required" class="form-control" " />                                                    <div class="input-group-append">

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>


                                        <div style="margin-top: 0.5cm;"></div>

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                                <div style="margin-top: 0.5cm;"></div>
                                                {{ form_errors(form.phoneNumber) }}
                                                <input type="tel" id="register_phoneNumber" value="{{ form.phoneNumber.vars.value }}" name="register[phoneNumber]" onkeypress="isPhone(event)" required="required" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control" pattern="^[0-9]{10}$" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>


                                        </div>

                                        <div style="margin-top: 0.5cm;"></div>
                                        <div class="row" >
                                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                                {{ form_errors(form.address) }}
                                                {{ form_widget(form.address) }}
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-1" hidden="hidden">
                                                {{ form_widget(form.image) }}
                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                        <div style="margin-top: 0.5cm;"></div>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultUnchecked" style="float: left">
                                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultUnchecked">Change Password</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                        <div style="margin-top: 0.5cm;"></div>

                                        <div id="register_password" >
                                            <div class="form-group row">
                                                {% for passwordField in form.password %}
                                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                                        {{ form_errors(passwordField) }}
                                                        {{ form_widget(passwordField) }}
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                                                {% endfor %}

                                            </div>
                                            <div style="margin-top: 0.5cm;"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    {{ form_widget(form.save,{'label':"Update"}) }}

                                    {{ form_widget(form._token) }}
                                    {{ form_errors(form) }}

                            </form>

                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
        </div>

    </div>    

{% endblock %}

  {% block javascripts %}

      <script>
          const checkBoxPwd = document.getElementById('defaultUnchecked');
          const pwdDiv = document.getElementById('register_password');
          pwdDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
          checkBoxPwd.addEventListener("change",function () {
              if (checkBoxPwd.checked == true){
                  pwdDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
              }else{
                  pwdDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";

              }
          });

      </script>

      <script>
          function isInputNumber(eve) {
              var ch = String.fromCharCode(eve.which);

              if (document.getElementById('register_idNumber').value.length < 9){
                  if (!(/[0-9]/.test(ch))){
                      eve.preventDefault();
                  }
              }else {
                  if (!(/[a-zA-Z]/.test(ch))){
                      eve.preventDefault();
                  }
              }

              if (document.getElementById('register_idNumber').value.length > 9){
                  eve.preventDefault();
              }
          }
          function isPhone(eve) {
              var ch = String.fromCharCode(eve.which);

              if (!(/[0-9]/.test(ch))){
                  eve.preventDefault();
              }
              if (document.getElementById('register_phoneNumber').value.length > 9){
                  eve.preventDefault();
              }
          }

      </script>

  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: You need separate form for that. You can start by copying that registration form you have and removing fields you don't need in your second form. Alternatively, you can have a single form with all fields common to both forms, and then make registration form use this common form as a subform, and then add some more fields specific to registration.

Comment: Have a look at Validation groups to validate or not the password/email/etc :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/validation_groups.html
You have the error `"Expected argument of type string"` because in your entity, you surely have cast the argument like : `public function setPassword (string $password)`. You could delete the cast `string` and try if the form doesn't override when you don't fill the password field

Comment: Thanks. It helped.